# pipelined Powershell cmdlet showing partial result?

Tags: powershell, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I am writing some C# program that executes PowerShell script.

I have the following line

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize:unlimited |
  Get-MailboxPermission |
    Where {($_.IsInherited -eq $false) -and !($_.user -like "S-1*") -and !($_.user -like "NT A*") } |
      select identity,user,@{n="objectid";e={(get-recipient -identity $_.user).ExternalDirectoryObjectId}}
```

basically it finds all mailbox permissions and retrieves corresponding `ExternalDirectoryObjectId` (which is same as Azure ObjectID)

The issue here is that the result returned is different from different machines. I would get all identity, user values, but for expression values that are in bold above, will only start to show up half way through the execution.

### for example on computer x

```
Identity|User|objectid
user1 |userA|
user2 |userA|
user2 |userB|
...   |...  |
user10|userC|
user11|userC|<objectID1>
user11|userD|<objectID2>
```

I noticed that on fast computer the objectIDs start showing up late, on slower computers it starts showing up early, however execution times are different.

How do I modify this so that objectGuid is retrieved for all entries? Why is pipelining not waiting until the calculated property `objectID` is properly retrieved?

If I write a short PowerShell script and use for loops for each mboxpermissions and retrieve them one by one, all of those objectGuids are retrievable. But it's slow.

Thanks for help and Please give me any suggestions!

Comment: Microsoft does specifically state **This property is for internal use and is not intended to be used in your code.** at [ReducedRecipient.ExternalDirectoryObjectId property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-api/ff436472(v=exchg.150)).

Comment: I apologize for my previous comment as it doesn't really answer the question or help the situation, but I wouldn't solely rely on that property unless you have thought it through.

Comment: Do you have a problem with C# parsing the result or is the problem PowerShell related? In case of the first: please add the C# code that executes the PS and captures the output. In case of the latter, you might want to remove the C# tag from your question.

Comment: Thanks guys, It's not just ExternalDirectoryObjectId I tried any other attributes (exchange guid, email-address,etc) any attribute that's calculated (in n=;e= section) does not get properly evaluated if the result is larger than a certain number. it gets evaluated only after certain amount of results has been passed. (null returned) It seems like some kind of initialization or timing issue, I can't be sure. Is there a way of making sure these "expression" is evaulated before it's returned? Thanks